# Android App will not function properly in production, but not receiving any errors or hints as to what is wrong

Tags: android

I have been developing an app over the past 3-4 months. I am using eclipse with the Android SDK plugin. I have tested and tested and tested before releasing the app on the market. I finally decided that the app was ready and created a production certificate using the SDK tools through eclipse. Exported the project as an android app and submitted it to the market. The app needs to access a remote server to receive the information for the content of the app. I am not sure why, but for some reason the apk that is produced by exporting the project from eclipse always returns a login failure message. If I connect my device and install/run from eclipse using the same login credentials everything works just fine. What have I forgotten or done wrong?

Answer (score 4):

I have no direct answer, but here's a bunch of things to check for:

- Have you checked the [logcat](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/adb.html#logcat) logs?
- Did you put appropriate permissions in the manifest ([INTERNET](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#INTERNET))?
- Have you tested the app remotely, or just locally?
- Is your server remotely accessible?
- Are you using addresses/URL's that are only accessible on your local network?
- Are you using [synchronous XHR requests](http://groups.google.com/group/phonegap/browse_thread/thread/47221dd79dad09ac/c86f761bdd49d72d?lnk=gst&q=android%20manifest%20question)?

Comment: - Yes I have checked logcat, no errors.
- Yes I have all the appropriate permissions.
- I have tested the app on both emulators and several different devices on both mobile connections and wifi, testing was done by running/installing via eclipse and the android sdk plugin.
- Yes server is remotely accessible.
- All urls are accessible from outside my network.

It does seem that when I build the project for production/distribution using the export in eclipse that I can no longer make an ajax request as it always returns a connection error which I do not receive when building in testing mode.

Comment: I figured I would provide you with a bit more information on what I am trying to accomplish and how I am doing this. I am using the phonegap plugin and therefore using ajax requests to obtain information from our servers. An end-user will have a website with us (build on rails) that could use the app to view/edit inventory on his/her webpage. Is it possible that the apk produced by exporting the project from eclipse is preventing me from using phonegap properly and being able to make the ajax request to my servers?

Comment: Are you doing synchronous ajax calls? If so, that may be your problem. I'm not sure why eclipse's export would change anything, but I've never used it. I added a link above.

Comment: I have found that I cannot make ajax request over HTTPS with a self-signed certificate. If anyone has any idea on how I can still make request over HTTPS in phonegap it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I am also faced with this issue but only on certain devices. These include HTC wildfird and HTC Legend. Other devices that I tested on, which worked are HTC Desire and Samsung Galaxy, strange? I did find that if you build the project using phonegap build it works fine on all devices